# Is this recursion well-defined?

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction, recursion

I have a recursion defined by
$$
f(n)=\max\{0,-c+pf(n-1)+(1-p)f(n+1)\}
$$

with $0.5<p \leq 1$ and $f(0)=R>0$ and $f(m)=0$ for some $m>0$. 
I am trying to show that $f(n)$ is decreasing in $n$ but I am not even sure if it is well-defined. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If $f(m) = 0$, you certainly can't have it decreasing for $n > m$.  Do you mean decreasing on $[0, m]$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $m$ is the first positive integer where $f$ is $0$.  Then for 
$0 < n < m$ you have $f(n) = -c + p f(n-1) + (1-p) f(n+1)$.  That
equation has solutions of the form $f(n) = - c n/(2p-1) + A + B (p/(1-p))^n$.
That function is  concave or convex, depending on the sign of $B$...

Comment: Thanks; this is really helpful. I only care about monotonicity and not convexity. I think using this I can show $f$ is strictly decreasing before the first time it becomes zero and then I need to show once it hits zero it can't become positive again.

Comment: For example, take $p = 2/3$, $c = 1$, $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = 0$, $f(2) = 1$, $f(3) = 6$,...

Comment: What you want to show is that if it hits $0$ and then becomes positive again, it won't become $0$ again.